# bug with using blocks in a for loop with fast enumeration

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

So im trying to build up a queue of blocks in an array, then execute the queue at a later stage, the queue is built up in a forloop that is using enumeration of a string that is used in the block.

```
NSArray *array = @[@"test", @"if", @"this", @"works"];
NSMutableArray *queue = [NSMutableArray new];

for(id key in array){

    //add the work to the queue
    void (^ request)() = ^{
        NSLog(@"%@", key);
    };

    [queue addObject:request];
    //request(); //this works fine if i just execute the block here, all the strings are printed
}

for(id block in queue){

    void (^ request)() = block;

    request(); //this just prints 'works' multiple times instead of all the other strings
}
```

do blocks not work with enumerated objects in a for loop (when not executed within the same for loop), or does this seem like a bug?

Comment: Turn on ARC and this won't happen.

Comment: Yeah, we are in the process of converting the app to arc, but its a monolithic project, so not that easy heh. i should have mentioned that in the question though, my bad

Comment: @JoshCaswell: "and this won't happen." From my reading of the ARC specification, that's not guaranteed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
[queue addObject:request];
```

to

```
[queue addObject:[request copy]];
```

UPDATE:
Blocks are created in stack. So `request` is a local variable. When you add it to NSMutableArray it is retained but it is not enough for blocks! Block  will be deleted anyway when you will leave `{}` - does not matter was it retained or not. You should copy it to heap first, then retain (by adding to the array).

Comment: It should be noted that the initial code doesn't copy the stack goodies (meaning all the variables you use in the block) while the second code does, hence your blocks were all referencing some addr which happened to be @"works"

Comment: @DanZimm actually the block did copy the key, it just stayed on the stack. The copy message is required to move it from the stack to the heap. It prints `works` only because he was lucky enough that the last instance of the block was still intact on the stack and available to execute.

Comment: @JasonCoco when i said "copy the stack goodies" I mean copy to the heap.. ;P

Comment: @avt - Surely this will leak the blocks as `copy` returns an owned block, and  `addObject:` will retain it again? Missing `release` or `autorelease`?

Comment: @CRD No leaks! Block will be released when `request` variable will go out of scope. And second time it will be released when deleted from array.

Comment: @avt - maybe I wasn't clear, surely the *copied* block is retained twice and will leak. The original stack block won't leak.

Comment: @CRD it will leak only if you are NOT using ARC. In other case it will not leak. I am not sure about implementation but maybe ARC will change `[request copy]` to `[ [request copy] autorelease]` or something like this. You can run this project (with ARC) and check leaks. I see no `release` instructions in code so I am 100% sure topicstarter uses ARC.

Comment: @avt - I assumed you are not using ARC, see the comments on the question itself.